# What is first responder?

Tags: ios, uikit, first-responder, uiresponder

According to Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/using_responders_and_the_responder_chain_to_handle_events?language=objc):

> When your app receives an event, UIKit automatically directs that
> event to the most appropriate responder object, known as the first
> responder.

Same documentation explain how *first responder* is determined:

> The hitTest:withEvent: method of UIView traverses the view hierarchy,
> looking for the deepest subview that contains the specified touch,
> which becomes the first responder for the touch event.

What I don't understand is why there is a property of UIResponder called `isFirstResponder`? And why `becomeFirstResponder` exists. Should not the *first responder* be determined dynamically by UIKit based on location of the specific touch event?

Additionally, `canBecomeFirstResponder` return `NO` for `UIView`, which is clearly incorrect since views do handle touch events.

The only way I can think that can resolve this confusion is if all these methods are relevant only to events of the type of shake, remote control and editing menu. But the documentation is not clear about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I don't understand is why there is a property of UIResponder called `firstResponder`?

There isn't. `UIResponder` does not have a public property named `firstResponder`.

> And why `becomeFirstResponder` exists.

The main use of `becomeFirstResponder` is to programmatically choose which text field gets keyboard events.

> Should not the first responder be determined dynamically by UIKit based on location of the specific touch event?

There are more kinds of events than touch events. For example, there are keyboard events and motion events. The first responder tracked by UIKit is for non-touch events. In other systems, this concept is usually called the “focus” or more specifically the “keyboard focus”. But (in iOS) the first responder can be a view that doesn't respond to keyboard events.

> Additionally, `canBecomeFirstResponder` return `NO` for `UIView`, which is clearly incorrect since views do handle touch events.

That's ok, because touch events don't really start at the first responder. They start at the view returned by `-[UIView hitTest:withEvent:]`.

> The only way I can think that can resolve this confusion is if all these methods are relevant only to events of the type of shake, remote control and editing menu. But the documentation is not clear about it.

There are more kinds of non-touch events that start with the first responder, but aside from that, you have resolved it correctly.

Comment: I'd just add the answer to the title question: the *first responder* is literally just the first object in the responder chain.

Comment: I meant `isFirstResponder` not `firstResponder`. Updated the original question. Nevertheless your answer is perfectly clear, thanks!

Comment: @Caleb This is what got me confused. First responder is first object in the responder chain only for **some** kinds of events. For touch events the first responder in the chain is not necessarily *THE firstResponder*.

Answer (score -1):

This is not a "quick answer" topic -- your best bet is to do some searching and read through several articles about it.

But, briefly...

`.becomeFirstResponder()` is often used to activate text fields without requiring the user to **tap** in the field. Common case is with multiple text fields (fill out the form type of interface), where you would automatically "jump" to the next field based on input:

```
myTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
```

Again, as you've already seen from glancing at the docs, there is much more to it than that... but far too much for an answer here.